# Problemas para sacer el promedio

Tags: javascript, html

estuve intentando crear un programa en js que calcule el promedio, que en realidad es unos de los ejercicios que hago, y llegue un punto muerto, ya que no termino de entender porque cuando uso select saca cualquier cosa. Y mi programa andaba en un principio pero yo intente hacerlo con select, para luego usar seletedIndex y desde allì todo fallo cuando volvi al código que si funcionaba ya no funcianaba porque en debe sacar el promedio bien hace cualquier otra cosa, en fin me gustaria saber porque de este comportamieto aqui mi código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ejercicio 50</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let medio = () =>{
            let nota1 = document.form.nota1.value;
            let nota2 = document.form.nota2.value;
            console.log(nota1,nota2);
            let medio1 = (nota1 + nota2) / 2;
            console.log(medio1);
            let obj = document.getElementById("contenedor3").innerHTML = `El promedio es ${medio1}`;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <head>
        <h1>Calculo de notas.</h1>
    </head>
    <main>
        <form name="form">
            <label>Nota:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nota1" onchange="">
            <label>Porcentaje</label>
            <div id="contenedor1"></div>
            <br>
            <label>Nota:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nota2" onchange="">
            <label>Porcentaje:</label>
            <div id="contenedor2"></div>
            <input type="button" value="calcular" onclick="medio()">
            <p id="contenedor3"></p>
        </form>
    </main>
    </script>
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia esto:

```
        let nota1 = document.form.nota1.value;
        let nota2 = document.form.nota2.value;
```

por esto:

```
        let nota1 = parseInt(document.form.nota1.value);
        let nota2 = parseInt(document.form.nota2.value);
```

Tal como lo tenias, el valor era mal interpretado. Usando la función [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) el valor es interpretado como entero.

> parseInt
>
> Convierte (parsea) un argumento de tipo cadena y devuelve un entero de
> la base especificada.

Comment: Muchas gracias, y cambia algo si se usa el input tipo number o si o si hay que pasarlo a entero. Gracias me habia olvidado de ese importante paso. Y mas si se trata de operaciones

Comment: Diria que no importa si el input es tipo number o no. Javascript lo interpreta como cadena igualmente. Lo del tipo number es más propio de HTML para filtrar lo que se pone en el campo más bien.  Tu por si acaso usa siempre parseInt cuando se trate de numeros.

Comment: Si esta respuesta soluciona tu pregunta deberias aceptarla para que no quede pendiente eternamente.  Aqui puedes aprender como se aceptan las respuestas válidas:  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas/428#428

Comment: De paso te invito a realizar el [tour] donde aprenderas como funcionamos y podrás ganar tu primera medalla!

Comment: Dale gracias por tu tiempo ya hago todo lo que me mencionaste